# Counting many-to-many field returns wrong value (Django)

Tags: python, sql, django, database, django-views

I have a model class `Student`:

```
class Student(models.Model):
   ...
```

and model class `Course`:

```
class Course(models.Model)
   students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

I now want to filter `Course` based on number of `Students` associated with a course. I tried:

```
Course.objects.annotate(student_count = Count('students'))
```

But for some reason, `student_count` is always returning one.

Let's say I create a course and add two students to it:

```
s1 = Student.objects.create()
s2 = Student.objects.create()
m1 = Course.objects.create()
m1.students.add(s1)
m1.students.add(s2)

print(Course.objects.all().first().students.count())
print(Course.objects.annotate(student_count = Count('students')).first().student_count
```

Prints

```
2
1
```

Why are these two values different? How can I filter courses based on the number of `Students`?

Comment: I think I have the same problem, and I'm not sure the below answers solve it...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is coming from annotation part. Every time that you add annotation part to your queryset, you also add a `group_by` to your query and if you don't add specific `group_by` to your queryset it automatically adds it for you (i.e. `group_by "id"`). Then your results become smaller and it'll remove duplicates from your query results (because of `group_by`). For instance look at these querysets:

```
1- Course.objects.all()[3].students.count()

2- Course.objects.annotate(student_count=Count("students"))[3].student_count
```

Although I tried to get third result from both of my querysets, the final result is different, because length of these two querysets are different (`Course.objects.all()` and `Course.objects.annotate(student_count=Count("students")`). So if you look at these queries which are related to our querysets:

```
1- {'sql': 'SELECT *, COUNT("students"."id") AS "student_count" FROM "course" LEFT OUTER JOIN "students" ON ("course"."id" = "students"."course_id") GROUP BY "course"."id" ORDER BY "course"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3'}


2- {'sql': 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "students" WHERE "students"."course_id" = 4'}
```

you can see the group by part in second query.
And also note that you should use second one for proper result (except for some situations that you know the exact index of your desired result in first queryset). Otherwise there are always situations which you might get different or wrong results because your first or last record might change in annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your scenario and the result is the same for two approach:

```py
class SOTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        s1 = Student.objects.create()
        s2 = Student.objects.create()
        m1 = Course.objects.create()
        m1.students.add(s1)
        m1.students.add(s2)

    @override_settings(DEBUG=True)
    def test_query(self):
        c1 = Course.objects.all().first()
        c2 = Course.objects.annotate(student_count = Count('students')).first()

        n1 = c1.students.count()
        n2 = c2.student_count

        self.assertEqual(n1, 2)
        self.assertEqual(n2, 2)
```

Result is OK:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.017s

OK
```

Maybe do you have [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#ordering)? Try removing `ordering`:

```py
        c1 = (
            Course
            .objects
            .order_by() #<-- this one
            .first())
        c2 = (
            Course
            .objects
            .order_by() #<-- this one
            .annotate(student_count = Count('students'))
            .first())
```